# ola-hallengren- rebuilding indexes for individual index

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

Could you please explain how the parameter `@Indexes=''` should be used when we are maintaining a single index from a table?

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'AdventureWorks',
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
@Indexes = ''
```

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. The specifics of the parameters can be found on Ola's website: [SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html).

Answer (score 0):

To update for a specific index you can use:

```
@Indexes = '[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName].[IndexName]'
```

To update for all indexes within a table you can use:

```
@Indexes = '[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]'
```

See also: https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html for reference.

Comment: thank you so  much for reply . I was missing to add the schema name before table name.  it has been solved my problem
cheers

Comment: Welcome, don't forget to mark the answer as answer if it helped you ;)